# How to force inline parameters in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: parameters, entity-framework-6, inline

I'm using Entity Framework 6, one of my tables has an integer column which actually keeps values from a C# Enum (not represented in DB in any way) and I  need to sort on that column based on Enum member names.

That is perfectly achievable for me via the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Foo] AS [t0]
ORDER BY 
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t0].[Bar] = 3 THEN 'A'
        WHEN [t0].[Bar] = 1 THEN 'B'
        WHEN [t0].[Bar] = 2 THEN 'C'
        ELSE 'D'
     END)
GO
```

The following LINQ code does exactly what I need (with caveat),

```
Foo.OrderBy(x => 
        x.Bar == 3 ? "A" :
        x.Bar == 1 ? "B" :
        x.Bar == 2 ? "C" :
        "D")
```

... caveat being the fact that EF converts inline values into parameters and it makes the query an order of magnitude slower.

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 3
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = 'A'
DECLARE @p2 Int = 1
DECLARE @p3 NVarChar(1000) = 'B'
DECLARE @p4 Int = 2
DECLARE @p5 NVarChar(1000) = 'C'
DECLARE @p6 NVarChar(1000) = 'D'
-- EndRegion
SELECT *
FROM [Foo] AS [t0]
ORDER BY 
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t0].[Bar] = @p0 THEN @p1
        WHEN [t0].[Bar] = @p2 THEN @p3
        WHEN [t0].[Bar] = @p4 THEN @p5
        ELSE @p6
     END)
```

Could someone please suggest how to force EF6 to inline values rather then use parameters in a particular case?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No, unfortunately, did not have much time to dig in.